# How to replace value in a column of dataframe python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can i find value "100 e pìu" in age column and replace it by 100 ?[This is a few rows of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTBSL.png)

Comment: did u try with regular expression?

Comment: try this -> df['Age'].str.replace(r'\s100 e pìu', 100, regex=True)

Comment: I try this, i create dftemp to find all rows have '100 e pìu' then replace it, it's work but i dont know how to apply it to main df, this is my code ->

dftemp = df[df['Age'] == '100 e più']
dftemp.replace('100 e più', '100', inplace = True)

Comment: It would be `df['Age'] = df['Age'].str.replace(r'\s100 e pìu', 100, regex=True)`

Comment: @lepsch
It's raise an error -> TypeError: repl must be a string or callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redefine column Age with new one, where values are replaced already:

```
df.Age = df.Age.replace('100 e più', 100)
```